# How to open a tex file in Texmaker from terminal in MacOS?

Tags: macos, texmaker

In Ubuntu I could simply run from the terminal:

```
texmaker file.tex
```

which opened my tex file in Texmaker. In MacOS, the `texmaker` command is not found, even though I have [Texmaker](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/) installed.

How can I achieve this in MacOS? Is there an equivalent command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once Texmaker is installed, you can add:

```
alias texmaker="open -a texmaker"
```

to your `.profile`. From now on, it should be possible to simply run from the command line:

```
texmaker file.tex
```

at the location where the `file.tex` is.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean [this](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/)  then you can install it with **homebrew** using this command:

```
brew cask install texmaker
```